# light gremlins - finding all the multiplication numbers of a prime in a range

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, math

I was trying to answer a question called "lightgremlins" on IEEEXTREME.
given a  array number of gremlins and the prime numbers each chose return the numbers in range that are still on after all gremlins toggled there prime multiplied numbers.

given the input:

```
30 3 2 3 5
```

output:

```
15
```

case consists of a hallway of length 30, and three gremlins. The action of the gremlins is as
follows:
The first gremlin flips switches `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30}`. All of these
switches were previously off, so they are now on.
The second gremlin flips switches `{3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30}`. Of these, `{6, 12, 18, 24, 30}`
were previously on, so they are now off. This results in the following switches being on: `{2, 3, 4, 8, 9,
10, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 26, 27, 28}`.
The third gremlin flips switches `{5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}`. Of these, `{10, 15, 20}` were previously on, so
they are now off. This results in the following switches being on: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 14, 16, 21, 22, 25,
26, 27, 28, 30}`.
Thus, there are 15 switches on at the end of the night.

Now my code is very straight forward:

```
testcases=int(input())
for i in range(0,testcases):
  array = input().split(' ')
  arrayofnumbers = [int(x) for x in array]
  #print(arrayofnumbers)
  onCount=0
  for j in range(1,arrayofnumbers[0]+1):
     primeCount=0
     for p in arrayofnumbers[2:len(arrayofnumbers)]:
        if j%p == 0:
            primeCount += 1
     if primeCount % 2 == 1:
         onCount += 1
print(onCount)
```

now this seems to work ok for small arrays or i think. i'm failing half of the test cases and i don't really understand why. perhaps this doesn't hold for very large arrays? perhaps my entire approach is wrong?

i have changed my code to use LCM and count amount of iterations but still this didn't solve the rest of the test cases pretty much stayed the same. this is my code:

```
from math import gcd

    testcases=int(input())
    for i in range(0,testcases):
      array = input().split(' ')
      arrayofnumbers = [int(x) for x in array]
      #print(arrayofnumbers)
      lcm = 1
      for i in arrayofnumbers[2:]:
          lcm = int(lcm * i / gcd(lcm, i))
      #print(lcm)

      if lcm >= arrayofnumbers[0]:
        onCount=0
        for j in range(1,arrayofnumbers[0]+1):
            primeCount=0
            for p in arrayofnumbers[2:len(arrayofnumbers)]:
                if j%p == 0:
                    primeCount += 1
            if primeCount % 2 == 1:
                 onCount += 1
        print(onCount)

      if lcm < arrayofnumbers[0]:
          numiters=int(arrayofnumbers[0]/lcm)
          onCount = 0
          extraonCount=0
          for j in range(1, lcm+1):
              primeCount = 0
              for p in arrayofnumbers[2:len(arrayofnumbers)]:
                  if j % p == 0:
                      primeCount += 1
              if primeCount % 2 == 1:
                  onCount += 1
          onCount = onCount * numiters

          for j in range(1, (arrayofnumbers[0]-(lcm*numiters))+1):
              primeCount = 0
              for p in arrayofnumbers[2:len(arrayofnumbers)]:
                  if j % p == 0:
                    primeCount += 1
              if primeCount % 2 == 1:
                extraonCount += 1
          onCount += extraonCount
        print(onCount)
```

using a different approach using sets of divisible numbers i'm not getting any test case timeouts but wrong answers and  a bit more correct test cases but still not a full right answer.
using this idea: 
[click link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034589/finding-the-number-of-divisible-integers-in-the-range-1-1000)

```
testcases=int(input())
for i in range(0,testcases):
  array = input().split(' ')
  arrayofnumbers = [int(x) for x in array]
  arrayOfon = []
  arrayIterate = []
  arrayPrimes = []

  for j in arrayofnumbers[2:]:
      arrayPrimes.append(j)
  arrayPrimes.sort()

  print(arrayPrimes)

  for j in arrayPrimes:
      num=0
      num = int(arrayofnumbers[0] // j)
      arrayOfon.append(num)

  print(arrayOfon)

  for j in arrayPrimes[1:]:
      arrayIterate.append(j)


  print(arrayIterate)


  for j in range(0, len(arrayIterate)):
      x = 0
      y = 0
      y = arrayOfon[0]
      x = y // arrayIterate[j]
      arrayOfon[0] = (y - x) + (arrayOfon[j+1] - x)



  print(arrayOfon[0])
```

Comment: Can you post an example input your attempts are alleged to fail on?

Comment: this is part of the problem, i submit my code to a site that checks around 20 test cases. i get 8 out of 20 right the rest wrong. i don't really know what input is alleged to fail because i can't see these test cases. very frustrating.

Comment: You seem to be using the 2nd number as the "number of gremlins" to deduce that there are three gremlins who toggle 2, 3 and 5. However, if there were four gremlins toggling 3, 2, 3 again and then 5, you would still get 15 lights on. Maybe the problem is you're not interpreting the input correctly? Maybe all the numbers after the first are the gremlin numbers? This is easy to check at any rate.

Comment: "Note: no two gremlins will choose the same prime number."

Comment: Can you also confirm that it is given that the switches are initially off? You'd also get 15 if the lights started out being on rather than off.

Comment: There are a group of gremlins that live in a long hallway in which there are a series of light switches.**At the beginning of each night, all of the light switches are off**. Then, one at a time, each gremlin does the following:

The gremlin chooses a prime number p, that has not been chosen by any previous gremlin that night.

The gremlin runs down the hallway flipping every pth switch.

The owner of the hallway, who is very concerned about his electricity bill, has asked you to determine how many switches are on at the end of the night.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. Maybe they're providing huge numbers as input, like 100 digits or something, because they think it's clever and want you to use the number theoretic approach rather than brute force. Your first attempt is apparently correct. Maybe the folks who made this exercise got it wrong? I mean, this may not get thorough peer review before going out the door; probably more like a hobby.

Answer (score 0):

Let `lcm` be the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), the counts will repeat every `lcm` numbers, so you don't need to loop over the whole range, just count how many switches are on in the range `1..lcm`, then multiply that by `int(n/lcm)` (i.e. how many times the sequence will repeat as whole) and add the counts for the last items, i.e. from `lcm*int*n/lcm)` to end.

Simple example:
if the number of switches is 33, and there are two gremlins: 2 and 3, `lcm(2,3)=6` so you don't need to count all the way from 1 to 33, because the counts will repeat every 6 switches, and will repeat `int(33/6)=5` times. So you only have to count the switches from 1 to 6, and multiply that count by 5, and add the count for the range 31...33

Comment: first of all thank you, still i think i am missing the point.

Comment: thanks again, still this doesn't seem the way to go. i think the algorithm approach is flawed. perhaps there is a mathematical way to do this.

Comment: this **is** the mathematical approach to it